# Intellij android project. Gradle 5.2.1. Cause: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I've started a new Android project with Intellij IDEA and got this error. I only changed the gradle version to 5.2.1 in gradle-wrapper.properties. Why does Intellij create a project that does not work? I've also tried to add this android project to an existing project as a module, with the gradle kts script and I've got the same error.

```
Cause: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1134)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:29)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeProductFlavor.copyVectorDrawables(IdeProductFlavor.java:80)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeProductFlavor.<init>(IdeProductFlavor.java:56)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeProductFlavorContainer.lambda$new$0(IdeProductFlavorContainer.java:42)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:29)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:29)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeProductFlavorContainer.<init>(IdeProductFlavorContainer.java:40)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$0(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:86)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:29)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:29)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:84)
at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:68)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:134)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:125)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:213)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.configure.KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:51)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:62)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:380)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:737)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:720)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:224)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:138)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:57)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:44)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:99)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:165)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:559)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:399)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:146)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:399)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:664)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:731)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:586)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:86)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:311)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208071). As a workaround use IntelliJ IDEA with JetBrains Runtime 8 instead of 11 (which is still experimental).

Comment: 8 is not avalibale in Ubuntu 19.04, so it's no longer a valid option!

Comment: @Pitel It's available with IntelliJ IDEA download.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the JetBrains Toolbox and click on install IntelliJ IDEA Community/Ultimate without the "+ JBR11" 
Worked for me on Manjaro Linux. Now my gradle build for my android project runs through.